# explode an array and add array keys

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, array-key

I have a string that looks like this,

> IT, MEDIA, ADVERTISING

I am then doing the following code.

`$criteria = explode(",", $string)`;

This obviously creates the following when print_r is run over the $criteria.

> array([0] => IT, [1] => MEDIA, [2] => 'ADVERTISING')

I using $criteria to match for keywords in a database in codeigniter application, I am wanting to using something like,

`$this->db->like($criteria);`

for this to work though I need the $criteria array to look like this,

> array([sector] => IT, [sector] => MEDIA, [sector] => 'ADVERTISING')

How can I do this?

Comment: Check the code/documentation, you are likely in need of array like `array('sector' => array('IT', 'MEDIA', 'ADVERTISING'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to make OR WHERE clauses with an array like this:

```
$criteria = array(
    0 => 'IT',
    1 => 'MEDIA',
    2 => 'ADVERTISING',
)
```

You can loop through it and use `like()` and `or_like()` methods:

```
foreach ($criteria as $index => $value) {
    if ($index == 0)
        $this->db->like('sector', $value);
    else
        $this->db->or_like('sector', $value);
}

// Produces WHERE sector LIKE '%IT%' OR sector LIKE '%MEDIA%' OR sector LIKE '%ADVERTISING%';
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP can't have multiple values with the same key.

Comment: gee.. And I was like 5sec from submitting a "solution" :)

Comment: +1 Nothing to include, except no language is able to do this. :) @Jordan: It does answer the question; its simply not possible to create such an array. Its like asking "How to fly to the moon with my car?". The only answer is "No way!" :D

Comment: @Jordan - it answers the question by saying that it isn't possible, which is a 100% correct answer

Comment: how can I do multiple likes using codeigniter active recorder based on the exploded string, which can be variable in length.....so stuck!

Comment: It does not solve the user's problem, which is how to perform this query in CodeIgniter using the given $string or $criteria. This "answer" is no better than "RTFM" at helping the poster more toward a solution to his actual problem.

Comment: The problem is that Udders didn't ask what he meant to ask.  The question he wants to ask is "How do I do ____ with codeigniter" and provide the above sample code.  If it said codeigniter I wouldn't have answered.  The user's question as stated has no answer but to change the like() function, or he misunderstands how the like() function works on the db object.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot build an array like this. The keys of the array are identical, so the values will overwrite each other.

Also I think that the method you are looking for is `where_in()`:

```
$names = array('Frank', 'Todd', 'James');

$this->db->where_in('username', $names);

// Produces: WHERE username IN ('Frank', 'Todd', 'James')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating your array `criteria` like this:

```
$criteria = array('sector'=>explode(",", $string));
```

#### OUTPUT

```
var_dump($criteria);

array(1) {
  ["sector"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "IT"
    [1]=>
    string(6) " MEDIA"
    [2]=>
    string(12) " ADVERTISING"
  }
}
```